# Convert Object Array to Array Object: Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
obj = {'a':['hello', 'hie'], 'b':['World', 'India']}
```

To

```
array = [{'a':'hello','b':'World'}, {'a':'hie','b':'India'}]
```

Best way to convert this or any build-in method for this conversion using JQuery.

Comment: *"Best way to convert this or any build-in method for this conversion using JQuery."* Write code looping through the properties of the object and building up the result. There isn't a shortcut.

Comment: Your mapping isn't that well defined. Please provide a few more examples and/or elaborate.

Comment: jQuery, now fabled as the Universal Swiss Army Knife of Web development... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Code,

```
obj = {'a':['hello', 'hie'], 'b':['World', 'India']}
var key = Object.keys(obj);
array = [];
for (var i = 0; i < obj['a'].length; i++){
  o = {}
  for (k in key){
    o[key[k]] = obj[key[k]][i]
  }
  array.push(o)
}
```

Comment: Don't use a for-in-loop for the `key` array. Also, some semicolons would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj = {'a':['hello', 'hie'], 'b':['World', 'India']};

var array = [];
for (var prop in obj)
    for (var i=0; i<obj[prop].length; i++) {
        var o = array[i] || (array[i] = {});
        o[prop] = obj[prop][i];
    }
```

No jQuery needed. With jQuery, it might look like this:

```
var array = [];
$.each(obj, function(prop) {
    $.each(this, function(i) {
        var o = array[i] || (array[i] = {});
        o[prop] = this;
    });
});
```

- slower and less readable. Do not use.